# Contract factory function running out of gas during Truffle test

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test, factory

Using openzeppelin library and truffle I am trying to make a Contract Factory that creates ERC20 tokens. I prefer to test it with Truffle using solidity and not javascript.

Here is the code from the Contract

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "zos-lib/contracts/migrations/Migratable.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

contract TokenFactory is Migratable {

    address[] public deployedTokens;

    function createToken(string name, string symbol) public {
        address newToken = new Token(name,symbol,msg.sender);
        deployedTokens.push(newToken);            
    }

    function getDeployedTokens() public view returns (address[]) {
        return deployedTokens;
    }

}

contract Token is StandardToken, Ownable {
    string public name = ""; 
    string public symbol = "";
    uint public decimals = 2;
    uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** decimals);

    constructor(string _name, string _symbol, address creator) {
        owner = creator;        
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    }    
}
```

and the Test

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/TokenFactory.sol";

contract TestTokenFactory {

    TokenFactory tk = TokenFactory(DeployedAddresses.TokenFactory());

    function testChildContractDeployed() public {

        tk.createToken("xxx","sym");
        address[] memory deployedTokens = tk.getDeployedTokens();
        Assert.equal(deployedTokens.length, 1, "Contact is not deployed");

    }

}
```

my truffle.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    local: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 7545,
      gas: 6000000,
      gasPrice:1,
      network_id: '*'
    }
  }
};
```

and the error after running `truffle test --network local`

> 1) TestTokenFactory
>          "before all" hook: prepare suite:
>        Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me some time to figure out what's wrong with you code (Thanks for the riddle). Here's how i get your test working :

1- I've change truffle.js to following :

```
networks: {
    local: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 7545,
     // gas: 6000010,
     // gasPrice:10000000000,
      network_id: '*'
    }
  }
```

but instead out of gas i've got revert exception,

[image]

to deal with I've created a migration script (2_initial_migration.js):

```
var TokenFactory = artifacts.require("./TokenFactory.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TokenFactory);
};
```

then the test passed with success

[image]

Comment: hi thanks for trying. the first part works, I get the revert message. When I put the 2_initial_migration.js in the migrations folder (I did not have any migration script before) I get the error : Error: Could not find artifacts for ./Migrations from any sources" I tried to change it to ../contracts/TokenFactory.sol and simple "TokenFactory.sol" but something is wrong. Which directory structure you have? Did you use openzeppeling? Maybe they mess something up with zos

Comment: I've installed openzeplin and zos using npm. try to run truffle compile-all then truffle migrate --reset then test the code. you don't have to change your contract code its working. Besides use the contract name as a file name.

Comment: I've uploaded the truffle's project on github https://github.com/bellaj/SEError (along the npm modules)..

Comment: that solved it!! many thanks!! I think I deleted Migrations.sol contract from the folder without knowing it.